# WP REST Api post posts into a remote wordpress website

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I have seen many examples on how to get posts from wordpress websites, but I haven't seen any example on how to post a post into a wordpress website using WP REST Api, except this update title example that is incomplete:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/posts/1',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
    },
    data:{
        'title' : 'Hello Moon'
    }
} ).done( function ( response ) {
    console.log( response );
} );
```

Could someone please show me a full working example of how to post a post into a remote wordpress website, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){
            //alert('a');
            //Perform Ajax request.
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://apibind.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
                type: "POST",               
                headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer ***************');},
                data: {"title" : " tttt","content":"some test content" },
                success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                },
                error:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
```